# How can I read the variable assigned in another component?

Tags: angular, angular5

I have two components for example.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-events',
    templateUrl: './events.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./events.component.css']
})
export class EventsComponent implements OnInit {
    sampleData : string ="some parent Data";
```

From this firstComponent I have a variable named sampleData. Now I want to show this sampleData into the second component at ngAfterViewInit() console.

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-footer',
    templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./footer.component.css']
})
export class FooterComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    constructor() { }
    @Input() sampleData : string;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log(this.sampleData);
    }

}
```

I went throught lots of tutorial that is passing data from template. But I am using templateUrl instead so I am confused at this early step of angular.

Any help please .

Comment: is firstComponent  a child component of secondComponent ?

Comment: @hana_wujira it can be anything. I want that variable show in FooterComponent  console

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a **`Shared Service`** to share data across components, if its having a parent,child relationship go for **`EventEmitters`**.

Example using a Shared Service

Use a service to save the category. And then you can use the same service to get the categoryType whenever you want it.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class AppMessageQueuService {

    sampleData: string;
    constructor() {

    }
    saveSampleData((cat:any){
        this.sampleData= cat;
    }
    retrieveSampleData(){
        return this.sampleData;
    }

}
```

Then you can inject this Service into both the components and save it from the first component like,

```
this.appMsgService.saveSampleData(yourcategory);
```

then retrieve in the second component as,

```
this.appMsgService.retrieveSampleData();
```

**[`STACKBLITZ DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-shared-service-paejns?file=app/components/component1/component1.component.ts)**

Comment: Can you give me example based on above

Comment: CHECK THE DEMO https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-shared-service-paejns?file=app/components/component1/component1.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

if first-component is a parent of second child u can pass the value in

second-component.html

```
<second-component [sampleData]="sampleData"></first-child>
```